# How to make an android app run in background when the screen sleeps?

Tags: android, google-maps, background-process, android-maps, android-wake-lock

I am developing a Tracking app, which keeps tracks of the user by getting his current location for every 3 secs. I am able to fetch the lat long values when the screen is on. but when the screen sleeps. i am unable to fetch the datas.

**CODE:**

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null)
    {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latLngcurrent = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(latitude)+" "+String.valueOf(longitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.format("latitude:%.3f longitude:%.3f",latitude,longitude));


    Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");
    Toast.makeText(this, "exiting LocationChanged ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The above given onLocationChanged method fetches the lat lon values for every 3 seconds. What should i do to make this method run even if the screen sleeps. I have read about Wakelock dont know how to implement it, any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Note:**  The app runs perfectly when multi tasking is done,

Comment: Use services https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: use Wakelog and Service class to do that

Comment: User IntentService instead

Comment: Intent Service is for short task. he need to fetch location continuously.

Comment: None of the above will work if the phone enters Doze mode on newer devices - even Wakelocks are ignored. Consider the battery drain having to keep waking the CPU and polling every 3 seconds - as a user this is a bad experience if it uses significant battery.

Comment: implement your tracking logic in a service and it will stay alive no matter if screen sleeps or app closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of `Service` to get location updates even if screen sleep or your app is not open.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyLocationService extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyLocationService";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 3000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    // create LocationListener class to get location updates
    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
    {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }
}
```

Add `MyLocationService` into your `AndroidManifest.xml` also:

```
<service android:name=".MyLocationService" android:process=":mylocation_service" />
```

Don't forgot to add below two permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**Start Service from an activity:**

You can start a `service` from an activity or other application component by passing an Intent (specifying the service to start) to `startService()`. The Android system calls the service's `onStartCommand()` method and passes it the Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyLocationService.class);
startService(intent);
```

**Update:**

You need to hold [partial wake lock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) to run service even after device screen off.

If you hold a partial wake lock, the CPU will continue to run, regardless of any display timeouts or the state of the screen and even after the user presses the power button.

To acquire wake lock:

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

To release it:

```
wakeLock.release();
```

Comment: I will try this now. is it possible to implement Service rather than extending? @Priyank

Comment: @RakeshPolo [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background. So, you need to extend your class to implement it. Check here for more details about [Service Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: i need to fetch the location from the class which has xml design. so i need to extend AppCompatActivity. Give me some ides on how to add the above code and make it working @Priyank

Comment: @RakeshPolo you can start service from your activity using `startService()` method. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I have created a class called MyLocationService and used your code. And in main activity inside Oncreate bundle i have used the intent to call the location service. But still i am unable to reach the MyLocationService class from my MainActivity class. I have given permissions and the service tag in manifest. @Priyank

Comment: @RakeshPolo When you start service, you will able to receive location updates in `onLocationChanged` method of `LocationListener` class. Check your logs accordingly.

Comment: I have kept breakup point in onLocationChanged method of LocationListener class. The code doesn't even flow into LocationListener class. Can you give me your mail id for further discusiion? Mine is rakesh.kannan.as@gmail.com

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659683/unable-to-start-service-intent-cmp-com-appstech-knowntrack-mylocationservice) I am getting this error now. @Priyank

Comment: Now the service is called but even now when then screen sleeps the app stops updating the values. Should I also add the asynchronous task inside the service class? @priyank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142845/discussion-between-priyank-patel-and-rakesh-polo).

Answer (score 2):

use job scheduler to get location after every 3 seconds it also works when screen sleep   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html

Comment: this is only available in API21+

Comment: Yes Mark Job scheduler is only available in API 21+

Comment: I know .. hence my comment ...?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) and implement [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   mLastLocation = location;
   if (mCurrLocationMarker != null)
   {
      mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
   }
   latitude = location.getLatitude();
   longitude = location.getLongitude();
   latLngcurrent = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

   Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(latitude)+" "+String.valueOf(longitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.format("latitude:%.3f longitude:%.3f",latitude,longitude));

   Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");
   Toast.makeText(this, "exiting LocationChanged ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I used service and implemented LocationListener but now getting this [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659683/unable-to-start-service-intent-cmp-com-appstech-knowntrack-mylocationservice) Can you figure this out? @user12345